# Is there a word for the mental state of laughter?

Tags: single-word-requests

We speak of *madness* when someone is in a fit of anger, and being *smitten* when someone is in love (with someone), etc. But what about when someone just can't stop laughing? i.e, when someone is "cracking-up" - is there a more formal word?

Comment: This brings to mind *maniacal* laughter.

Comment: @cornbreadninja - Exactly! Isn't it akin to being *mad* in that it's uncontrollable? Like that famous video on YT of the talkshow guy laughing at a castrated man's voice>?

Comment: __Stupidity__. You can't think and laugh at the same time.

Comment: ***Smitten*** just happens to be a metaphorical usage often applied to ***infatuation, being in love***. But you can be smitten by a sword, disease, lightning,... And although ***to be mad*** can mean ***to be angry***, there's no particular reason to associate ***anger*** (displeasure) with ***madness*** (insanity). This question is based on the false premise that *Anger is to Madness as Love is to Being Smitten as XXXX is to Laughter*. That's just six more-or-less unrelated terms, not three examples of some meaningful "relationship".

Comment: What exactly is supposed to be accomplished by closing a question that was open for more than ten years, seen 3K times, and has several answers, some of which have a nonnegligible number of upvotes? Surely it would be better to leave the question open, so that the existing answers are exposed to competition. The question is quite clear as it is. If one believes that there is no word that the question seeks, one should post that as an answer, rather than treat it as a reason for closing the question.

Comment: @jsw29 I don't think lifetime is a good metric for the quality and germaneness of questions. And cleaning is done all over the network, to keep the overall quality high. Besides, if a question has answers, it will only be closed, and not removed. But I don't really see a valid reason to close it, either.

Comment: @Joachim, the problem is precisely that 'if a question has answers, it will only be closed, and not removed'. Closing a question with answers perversely privileges the answers posted before the closing by insulating them from competition. That reduces the 'overall quality' of the site by misleading the future visitors to the page (particularly the casual ones, who are not familiar with how the site works) into thinking that the existing answers are the best that can be given to the question (which they may or may not be - the best way to find out is to see whether anybody posts a better one).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We speak of ***hysterical*** laughter.

Comment: It is puzzling why the OP accepted this answer, as it doesn''t seem to answer the question as posed. The question sought a word for a mental state behind laughter (i.e. for something **distinct** from laughter); this answer offers an adjective for a particular **kind** of laughter.

Comment: *In hysterics* would be a noun formulation.

Answer (score 6):

[Hilarity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hilarity)

Comment: @Adel, that, combined with a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/hilarity?s=t), should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

They are *amused*. [Defined as](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/amused)  being entertained by something.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the state of euphoria as on directly link to laughter and the ease or comfort, one feels towards a subject, situation ; usually some potentially lesser threat. Exemple : laughing after one falls or smiling in the face of profoundly perplexing ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, if the news anchor was uncontrollably laughing at a castrated man, his sense of humor would be macabre. Thus, placing his uncontrolled laughter at deranged laughter.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone exhibiting uncontrolled emotion is unrestrained, meaning they don’t hold back.

"laugh **unrestrainedly**!"
(An adverb form of [unrestrained](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/unrestrained))